# Сумма Integer полей в модели

Tags: python, django

Есть модель, например

```
t1 = models.IntegerField(...)
t2 = ...
t3 = ...
t1name = models.CharField(...)
t2name = ...
...
```

t1, t2, t(n) - цифры.
Я делаю выборку из базы на 1 объект и необходимо посчитать сумму только этих полей (t(n))
Шепчет кэп, что не нужно мне делать так:

```
a = Quote.objects.filter(user__username=Fool).order_by('-id')[0]
itog= a.t1 + a.t2 + a.t3 ....
```

Comment: Кстати, первый и последний объект можно получить через методы first() и last() соответственно. Пожалуйста, не делайте срез одного объекта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немножко дополню, чтоб было яснее. Предположим у нас есть модель

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    t1 = models.IntegerField(...)
    t2 = ...
    t3 = ...
    t1name = models.CharField(...)
    t2name = ...
```

Мы получаем один объект `obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)`. Далее будем работать именно с такими обозначениями.

В django вся служебная информация о полях сваливается в `MyModel._meta.fields`. Соответственно задача сводится к тому, чтобы отфильтровать этот список в поиске нужных нам полей, потом получить их значения и выдать в качестве суммы. Динамически получить значения полей, как и во всём питоне, можно получить через `getattr`. Ну что, давайте какой-то пример накидаем

Для начала попробуем получить `t1`

```
>>> [field for field in MyModel._meta.fields if field.name == 't1']
[<django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: t1>]
```

Отлично, работает. Но нам надо получать все t[n]. Давайте напишем регулярку!

> и будет на одну проблему больше

```
import re
>>> [field for field in MyModel._meta.fields if re.match(r'^t\d+$', field.name)]
[<django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: t1>, <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: t2>, <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: t3>, <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: t4>]
```

Регулярка выбирает все поля, которые начинаются на `t` и дальше идёт одно или несколько чисел.

А вдруг у нас будет не `IntegerField`? Давайте ещё одну проверку сделаем на тип поля:

```
>>> [field for field in MyModel._meta.fields if re.match(r'^t\d+$', field.name) and field.get_internal_type() == 'IntegerField']
[<django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: t1>, <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: t2>, <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: t3>, <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: t4>]
```

Вот теперь то нас никто не обманет. Осталось только просуммировать значения из этих полей и добавить это всё в качестве метода экземпляра модели:

```
def sum_f_fields(self):
    field_names = [field for field in MyModel._meta.fields if re.match(r'^t\d+$', field.name) and field.get_internal_type() == 'IntegerField']
    values = [getattr(self, field.name, None) or 0 for field in field_names]
    returm sum(values)
```